# For a set of line numbers ...Extract content between first and last occurence of different patterns

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I have a similar content in a file. I have a list of line numbers with me say 1,2, 4.

1. Can feed all the required line #s
2. Extract the contents between the **first** occurence of  and **last** occurence of `</book>`

**Data:**

```
</p><p>abc</p></book><book><p style="text-indent:0em;">def</p></book><book><p>ghi</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book><book><div><p>  
</div><p>123</p></book><book><p style="text-indent:0em;">456</p><p>789</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book><book><div><p>  
<div><p>nothing !!!</p></div>  
</p><p>ABC</p></book><book><p style="text-indent:0em;">DEF</p></book><book><p>GHI</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book><book><div><p>JKL</p></div></book><div>
```

**Input Line #s:** 1, 2, 4 (Which I want to feed in the command)

**Desired Output:**

```
<book><p style="text-indent:0em;">def</p></book><book><p>ghi</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book>
<book><p style="text-indent:0em;">456</p><p>789</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book>
<book><p style="text-indent:0em;">DEF</p></book><book><p>GHI</p><p style="text-indent:0em;"></book><book><div><p>JKL</p></div></book>
```

Comment: In your output `text-indent: 0em;` string was occurs once in first and second line, but once in the third line. Can you explain why?

Comment: Thanks Egor for pointing out the error. Its now corrected. Pls look at the updated desired output.

Comment: The input is not valid XML. If it were, you might try `xmllint --xpath ...` or some similar tool.

Comment: yes @Olaf . We can't expect a valid exml in each line in input. But inside <book> it will be a properly formed xml. Hence using a shell command, want to fetch between first occurence of <book> and last occurence of </book>. After that, I need to apply XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Extract specific lines**

In your four-line example to extract the 1st, 2nd and 4th line would be easy by deleting the 3rd line:

```
sed 3d file
```

But your file is probably more complicated, so a more general solution would be to do

```
sed -e 1b -e 2b -e 4b -e d file
```

So for each line that should be kept you jump to the end of the script with `b` and delete all remaining files.

For a longer list of line numbers you may want to generate the script:

```
sed $(for i in 1 2 4; do echo "-e ${i}b"; done) -e d file
```

But it seems that it's not about the line numbers, but whether there are `<book>`s on that line. If this is true, you better forget about the line numbers and do

```
sed '/<book>/!d'
```

**2) extracting the contents**

Greedy `*` of regexp is not a friend for tasks like this. That's why my personal version of `sed` has an option `o` to the `s` command to replace `o`nly by the matched part:

```
sed '/<book>/!d;s_<book>.*</book>_&_o'
```

But this won't work for you, so you need some more regex juggling:

```
sed '/<book>/!d;s_<book>_\n&_;s_.*\n__;s_\(.*</book>\).*_\1_' file
```

If your version of `sed` doesn't support `\n` in the replacement string, use an actual newline (escaped by a backslash):

```
sed '/<book>/!d;s_<book>_\
&_;s_.*\n__;s_\(.*</book>\).*_\1_' file
```

Comment: First of all Appreciate you for the clear and neat presentation of Answer. I am trying out more examples and let you know soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10;

my @lines = (1, 2, 4);

while(<>) {
    next unless $. ~~ @lines;
    chomp;
    s#.*?(<book>.*</book>).*#$1#;
    say
}
```

Comment: @Sato . . Please guide me on where will I provide the input file. Thanks.

Comment: On the command line or on `stdin`: `perl script.pl file.html`, or `perl script.pl <file.html`.